# Загрузить данные из текстовых файлов, в заданном каталоге,при этом данные из каждого файла должны представляться как отдельные текстовые документы

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

имею такую задачу, мне необходимо загрузить данные из текстовых файлов, в заданном каталоге, при этом данные из каждого файла должны представляться как отдельные текстовые документы.
Данные мне нужны для векторизатора scikit-learn.

Как я понял мне необходимо загрузить текстовые файлы (данные) из папки (ну например /docs) в массив, элементы которого - символы

С помощью функции `sklearn.datasets.load_files('/docs')` это можно осуществить?

Просто используя функцию выше я получаю следующее:

```
 {'data': [], 'filenames': array([], dtype=float64), 'target_names': [], 'target': array([], dtype=float64), 'DESCR': None}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Задавайте корректный вопрос и получите корректный ответ

Для решения необходимо было разбросать все документы по категориям в самом каталоге (может и не нужно было, но я следовал [документации функции](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html#sklearn.datasets.load_files)) примерно таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого необходимо воспользоваться функцией `load_files('path')` файлы успешно будут загружены, но при этом необходимо учитывать что на выходе получается словареподобный объект, которые не отображает файлы и слова, для дальнейшей манипуляции с файлами необходимо конкретизировать задачу, у меня это была задача нормализации данных и векторизация Tf-idf. Поэтому для меня решение оказалось следующим

```
text_train_subset = load_files('/content/docs1/')
# загрузка файлов 

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
# класс из sklearn.feature_extraction.text 
sorted_vocabulary = {k: v for k, v in sorted(vectorizer.vocabulary_.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
# сортировка словаря всех слов в файлах
```

Comment: не похоже на ответ на заданный вопрос. внесите, пожалуйста, больше деталей, нажав [edit]